# WaterfallDialog needed for a simple prompt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework

I am new to the BotFramework v4 coming from v3, having a hard time understanding the dialog concept of v4

I am trying to ask the user for example his age and then I want to end the conversation I tried to dynamically add the dialog to the `DialogSet` but both `ContinueDialogAsync` and `ResumeDialogAsync` will not get called. The conversations ends right after the prompt and the answer will not be awaited.

Here is the call of the TextPrompt:

```
dialogContext.Dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt("age"));
return await dialogContext.PromptAsync("age", new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("How old are you?")
});
```

Do I really need to implement a WaterfallDialog with a single step to achieve this?

Comment: This doc explains some differences and similarities between V3 and V4: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Waterfall Dialogs. The [Simple Prompt Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/04.simple-prompt/SimplePromptBot.cs) should get you started.

[Relevant code snippet](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/04.simple-prompt/SimplePromptBot.cs#L72):

```
if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
{
    // A prompt dialog can be started directly on the DialogContext. The prompt text is given in the PromptOptions.
    await dialogContext.PromptAsync(
        "name",
        new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your name.") },
        cancellationToken);
}

// We had a dialog run (it was the prompt). Now it is Complete.
else if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Complete)
{
    // Check for a result.
    if (results.Result != null)
    {
        // Finish by sending a message to the user. Next time ContinueAsync is called it will return DialogTurnStatus.Empty.
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Thank you, I have your name as '{results.Result}'."));
    }
}
}
```

For additional info, I posted a similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045440/getting-value-stored-in-a-variable-in-botframework-suggested-actions/55049809#55049809) and I had a coworker with a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029213/c-sharp-bot-framework-v4-get-userinput/55048606#55048606).

Answer (score 0):

okay, I want to answer that question by myself:
The botframework v4 has an `IBot` interface and every message got routed through your singleton instance of the implemented interface. So my thought was that started dialogs will get the responses of an user directly. Instead your implementation of `IBot` needs to create a dialogContext and also needs to continue the active dialog in the `OnTurnAsync` method:

```
var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(context, cancellationToken);

if (dialogContext.ActiveDialog is null)
{
    await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(AgeDialog),
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
else
{
    await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
}


await _accessor.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(context, false, cancellationToken);
```